# Getting most frequent color form image

Tags: java, android, image-processing, pixel

I'm writing an app that captures a video from the camera of the Android device. I'm trying to get all the frames of a video on every one second. this video contains specific color sequence Suppose (Red, Orange, White, Black, Violet). Actually regarding videos, after every second one color is broadcast on laptop screen and i need to make video of this broadcasting sequence then i need to identify sequence of color. I already did that part to get image frames from video.

Now my main question is that, how can i get identify each image color from set of image frames. I want output like below :

```
(image1, red)
(image2, white)
(image3, black)
(image4, Yellow)
(image5, orange)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the release of Android Lollipop you now have access to a helper class called `Palette`.
With it you can extract the main colors of your bitmap, which you can get from frames of your video.
Here's a blog post explaining how to use the class:
https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/extracting-colors-to-a-palette-with-android-lollipop/

Comment: but my color sequence is not fix. Any color could be there in video. 0 to 255. Is this work perfectly?

Comment: Yeah the color isn't fixed. The Palette class picks up the prominent colors in any image you give it.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at my app Color Extractor (https://github.com/RacZo/ColorExtractor), it is a little app that I build as a proof of concept but it shows how to use the new Palette and Palette Builder classes to get colors and swatches from an image, you can even take a photo with the camera to extract the colors from it.